# React State Storing & Outputting Duplicate Values every re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, state

Whenever my page loads I execute the useEffect() function below to retrieve data from firebase and set it to my local state `calendarList` but every time the page renders it makes a duplicate of the data and pushes is to the state so I have twice as many objects stored. How can I prevent this from happening?

STATE

```
const [calendarList, setCalendarList] = useState([]);
```

USE EFFECT - executes on page load

```
useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("calendars")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const calendarArray = [];

        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         
          calendarArray.push(doc.data()); push all doc obejects to calendar array
        });
       

        setCalendarList(calendarArray); //set state 
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: The reason is because useEffect is a life cycle method equivalent to `componentWillmount` and `componentDidmount` it runs twice per component

Comment: so what can I do to compensate for that when it occurs?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a custom hook, perhaps.

create a new file and call it as you wish, but gurus out there says it must have to start with use

```
//useCalendar.js

import {useState, useEffect} from "react"; 

const useCalendar = (userId) => {
  const [calendarList, setCalendarList] = useState([]);

    const addItem = (item) => {
      // use this to add mow items
    };

    const cleanList = () => {
       setCalendarList([]);
    }

    const getItemById = (id) => {
      // use this to get an item
    };

  useEffect(()=> {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .collection("calendars")
      .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        const calendarArray =  snapshot && snapshot.map(doc => doc.data());
       
        setCalendarList(calendarArray || []);
      });
  },[userId, list]);

  return {
    calendarList,
    addItem,
    cleanList,
    getItemById
   };

}

export default useCalendar;
```

now at yow component use it like

```
const component = () => {
  const { calendarList, addItem, cleanList, getItemById } = useCalendar(userId);
...

}
```